# Export folder of FBX to GLB

Tags: python, scripting

I have made a little script that takes an FBX, removes the materials, add a material again, and attaches an Image Texture. It then saves the result in a GLB with Texture combined.

This works fine for a single FBX. However, I want to run this on a folder of FBX files. There I hit a number of troubles, as the system continuously complains about context issues, selected_objects and active_object not existing etc.

This is the code that I now use to do this. Do you have any suggestion as to what would solve this problem?

```
import bpy
import os
import random
import shutil



# Clear existing data
bpy.ops.wm.read_factory_settings(use_empty=True)

# Paths (modify these paths according to your own setup)
root_dir = "path_to\\models"
textures_folder = "path_to\\textures"

# Iterate over all FBX files in the root directory
for fbx_file in os.listdir(root_dir):
    if fbx_file.lower().endswith('.fbx'):
        fbx_path = os.path.join(root_dir, fbx_file)
        
        # Import FBX
        bpy.ops.import_scene.fbx(filepath=fbx_path)

        # Delete all existing materials
        for material in bpy.data.materials:
            material.user_clear()
            bpy.data.materials.remove(material)

        # Create a new material
        new_mat = bpy.data.materials.new(name="MainMaterial")
        new_mat.use_nodes = True
        bsdf = new_mat.node_tree.nodes["Principled BSDF"]

        # Get a list of all image files in the textures_folder
        valid_extensions = ('.jpg', '.jpeg', '.png', '.tga', '.bmp')
        image_files = [f for f in os.listdir(textures_folder) if f.endswith(valid_extensions)]

        # Select a random image texture from the folder
        random_image = random.choice(image_files)
        image_path = os.path.join(textures_folder, random_image)

        # Load the image texture
        image_texture = bpy.data.images.load(image_path)

        # Create an Image Texture node and link it to the material
        texture_node = new_mat.node_tree.nodes.new('ShaderNodeTexImage')
        texture_node.image = image_texture
        new_mat.node_tree.links.new(bsdf.inputs['Base Color'], texture_node.outputs['Color'])

        # Assign the new material to all objects
        for obj in bpy.context.scene.objects:
            if obj.type == 'MESH':
                if len(obj.data.materials) == 0:
                    obj.data.materials.append(new_mat)
                else:
                    obj.data.materials[0] = new_mat

        # Define the GLTF export path
        model_name = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(fbx_path))[0]
        gltf_folder = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(fbx_path), "GLTF")
        os.makedirs(gltf_folder, exist_ok=True)
        gltf_path = os.path.join(gltf_folder, model_name + ".glb")

        for obj in bpy.context.scene.objects:
            obj.select_set(True)
            
        override = bpy.context.copy()
        override['selected_objects'] = list(bpy.context.scene.objects)
        override['active_object'] = bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active
        bpy.ops.export_scene.gltf(override, filepath=gltf_path, export_format='GLB', export_materials='EXPORT', export_colors=True)


        # Copy the texture to the GLTF folder
        texture_copy_path = os.path.join(gltf_folder, os.path.basename(image_path))
        if not os.path.isfile(texture_copy_path):
            shutil.copy(image_path, texture_copy_path)
        
        # Clear the scene for the next FBX file
        bpy.ops.wm.read_factory_settings(use_empty=True)
        
        print(f"Processed {fbx_file} and exported to GLTF")

print("All FBX files processed")
```

Thanks in advance for all help!

Comment: I don't think it´s possible to override the context properties "active_object" and "selected_objects" with the old override by adding the positional attribute to the operator (bpy.ops.export_scene.gltf(override, ...)). Try to kick out the whole override stuff and add use_selection=True to the exporter. `bpy.ops.export_scene.gltf(filepath=gltf_path, export_format='GLB', export_materials='EXPORT', export_colors=True, use_selection=True)`